# What does first line of an if let statement used to unwrap an optional in Swift translate to

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a good understanding of what optionals are and why they are needed. But I am curious as to what exactly happens under the hood in the first line of an if let statement that unwraps an optional. Here's some code:

```
var optionalInt : Int?

if let optionalInt = optionalInt {
    print("I have an integer value.")
} else {
    print{"I have a nil value")
}
```

Now I know that the first line is the equivalent to "if optionalInt contains a value execute this block of code", but my question is how does the code mean that. What really happens when the compiler reads the first line of the if let statement?

Answer (score 0):

`Optional<T>` is an enumeration with two cases:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case .none // a.k.a. nil
    case .some(wrapped)
}
```

It works kind of like a tuple of the type `(isPresent: Bool, wrapped: T)`. When you're conditionally unwrapping an optional like this, the `isPresent` boolean flag is checked. If it's true, then `wrapped` is bound to whatever variable name you provided. Otherwise, the `else` case is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know that the symbol `=` in `if`-`let` notation is not an assignment operator nor leading initial value. It's just a separator.

The semantics of `if`-`let` is defined as:

- if the right hand side of the **separator** is evaluated to a non-nil value, establish the declaration of local variable on the left hand side with unwrapped value and non-Optional type, then execute the `true`-block.
- if the right hand side of the **separator** is `nil`, execute the `else`-block if any.

So, your interpretation *"if optionalInt contains a value execute this block of code"* is not completely wrong, just that you cannot take this part `let optionalInt = optionalInt` as an assignment nor a normal variable declaration nor a simple non-nil condition.

Comment: Awesome. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to consider two things:

- Variable scope, and is something `nil`
- What to do if it's `nil`

Maybe a fair way to address this is comparing `if` to `guard`. Using your example:

```
var optionalInt:Int?
if let newOptionalInt = optionalInt {
    print("I will do something because I **do have** a value")
} else {
    print{"I will do something **else** because I **do not have** a value")
}
```

Which is pretty much the same as:

```
guard newOptionalInt = optionalInt else {
    print{"I will do something because I **do not have** a value")
}     
print{"I will do something **else** because I **do have** a value")
```

- The biggest change I did is remnaming the *most* local `optionalInt` to `newOptionalInt`. That's the variable scope piece.
- Both `guard` and `if` work the same - branch processing if you have a value or not.
- Speaking for me, I prefer the `guard` when possible - particularly at the start of a `func`. It's *much* more clearer coding as to your intent.